# Why is chrpath limited to maximum length 6?

Tags: dynamic-linking

I'm trying to change the RUNPATH of a shared object but I get an error that it cannot be longer than 6 characters.  What is the reason for this?  This is `chrpath` version 0.16 on Raspbian.

```
$ chrpath -r ../../.. lib/vlc/plugins/access_output/libaccess_output_srt_plugin.so
lib/vlc/plugins/access_output/libaccess_output_srt_plugin.so: RUNPATH=../lib
new rpath '../../..' too large; maximum length 6
```

I was able to set a longer path using `patchelf`.

Answer (score 2):

`chrpath` can’t add an `RPATH` tag if one isn’t present, and it can’t extend one; as a result, the new path must be of equal length to or shorter than the existing path. Your library started out with a `RUNPATH` set to `../lib`, so `chrpath` can only replace that with a path of six characters at most.

`patchelf` doesn’t have that limitation.

Comment: Oh!  Weird.  I guess that answers the question, but why??  This limitation doesn't make sense.

Comment: [chrpath](https://github.com/jwilk-mirrors/chrpath/blob/trunk/chrpath.c) doesn't fully re-write the ELF file, giving it the ability to change offsets and allocations. Instead it uses the existing space that was allocated for the prior value. It similar to changing string contents in a binary manually with a hex editor - everything must fit the existing space.

patchelf is implemented differently.

Answer (score 1):

The new set of paths for `rpath` or `runpath` [can't be larger then the one originally stored (Code Yarns site)](https://codeyarns.com/tech/2017-11-01-how-to-change-rpath-or-runpath-of-executable.html#gsc.tab=0).

Your previous `rpath` was exactly 6 chars, it's `../lib` in your example.
You can't extend it.

As @R Perrin stated, `chrpath` doesn't rewrite the whole ELF file using existing space that is itself limited to what was set originally.